# Customer activation field

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, collection, customer-attribute

I am working on one custom module where i need to show customers.After getting the customer fields i am little confused that for customer activation which field is to be set.Is `Active` or `Customer Activated` ? I am trying to update customer info and it updates customer activated but not is active.
My code is follow :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model  = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($id);
             $model   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($data['email'])
            ->setCustomerActivated($data['is_active'])
            ->setIsActive($data['is_active'])
            ->setGroupId($data['group_id']);
             $model->save();
```

I want to set customer status either active or not on basis of either `is active` or Customer Activated.

Comment: You should check this article from inchoo for creating customer programatically.. it might help http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/

Comment: I know and i can create users but i want to know how to activate or deactivate user.which field is used for this purpose.Hope you got what i want to say

Comment: @Adda did you got the way to activate or deactivate the user

Answer (score 1):

There's a certain excellent (free) extension from certain distinguished Magento community member, that does just that:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-activation.html

Use it as a template for whatever you plan to build.

Comment: thanks but again sorry to say that i can't follow your way.I am working on custom extension so only need guidelines about DB field.

Comment: Sure you can, studying other people code is the best way to learn how to do things right (i.e. in Magento way).

Answer (score 0):

It's customer_activated.

The correct code is:

```
$customer->getData('customer_activated')
$customer->setData('customer_activated', 1)
```

Comment: table name where i can find customer_activated

Answer (score 0):

For me worked on Magento 1.9:

```
$customer->setData('am_is_activated',1);
```

Where 1 is not activated and 2 is activated,

regards